# Mention the Encoding Type while creating the XML file QTP

Tags: xml, vbscript, qtp

I am using an XML file to report the details of the execution in QTP test, where I have to report the data entered in each field.

The data contains special characters (bevcause it could be in different languages such as Japanese, Chinese, etc) because of which the reporting XML is crashing while opening in a browser.

I came to know that mentioning the encoding type while creating the XML will solve the issue.

I am using the `XMLUtil.CreateXML` statement.

Comment: This question is confused. What issue? What is the exact error message? Also, where is your code sample?

Answer (score 1):

It should be UTF-8 encoding.
But QTP by default saves the file in the UTF-8 encoding only.